# What's the best way to import a blender .obj into an Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, opengl-es, blender

I have a 3-d "book" which I've exported as an .obj from blender. I would like to put it into my Android Studio Project. Right now i can parse the .obj file and display the book on screen but the book is all one color and without any texture data. Now I know I can try to add a lot of this stuff through OpenGL-es and make it look like the blender model myself but I'm wondering if there is an efficient way to import blender .obj into Android Studio where a lot of the work is already done for me.